# Cannot connect my android device to my python socket server?

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I have a python socket server which my android devices are meant to connect to but my android emulator is able to connect to it but my phone is not able to connect to it and gives the error ETIMEDOUT. Can anyone tell what is wrong with it?

Python server:

```
    import socket               
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
    host = socket.gethostname() 
    port = 12345                
    s.bind((host, port))        
    s.listen(10)                 
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()     
        print(addr)
        c.send(bytes('Thank you for connecting','utf-8'))
        c.close()
```

Android Client:
Client.java:

```
    package com.example.abhishekroul.clientapp;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.TextView;

   //import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
     import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.net.Socket;
     import java.net.UnknownHostException;
     public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
       String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
String response="";
TextView textResponse;
Client(String addr,int port, TextView textResponse)
{
    dstAddress=addr;
    dstPort=port;
    this.textResponse=textResponse;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void ...arg0)
{
    Socket socket=null;
    try
    {
        socket=new Socket(dstAddress,dstPort);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream= socket.getInputStream();
        while((bytesRead=inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        }
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response="UnknownHostException:"+e.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response="IOException:"+e.toString();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
    textResponse.setText(response);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.abhishekroul.clientapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText address, port;
TextView response;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
    response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

}

public void funcConnect(View v)
{
    Client client= new Client(address.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString()),response);
    client.execute();
}

public void funcClear(View v)
{
    response.setText("");
}


}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.abhishekroul.clientapp" >
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

on emulator its connecting but on an android phone it shows ETIMEDOUT error.

Comment: The problem may lay in the IP address. What do you type in the adresse EditText? Is it visible from the device? Is it connected using a Wifi network?

Comment: yes it is connecting via wifi and generally enter the ip address i receive through my pc using cmd command ipconfig

Comment: You may have either a firewall or an anti-virus blocking the call. Try to do a telnet from an other computer connected to the same network: 'telnet ip_address port'.

Comment: thank you so much for your help KLiFF turrns out our campus wifi doesnt allow local connection i tried it with a mobile hotspot and it was working but still thank you for looking at my problem

Answer (score 0):

So after lot of testing I have found the solution to the problem by using the port 80 the HTTP protocol which is generally never blocked as HTTP based processes will stop as this port is generally used by this protocol so it is better to user port 80 for socket creation.